# Mosty pythonic way to change a variable stored in two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists. Each contain the same variable, "board123". I want to change some of the properties of "board123" and have both lists entry for the "board123" updated. What is the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Currently I am searching each list for their entry of "board123" and updating them individually. My C++ experience though says this is mind-blowingly wasteful both in computation time and code space. I'd like to use something like pointers. I'd have a pointer in each list that points to a single "board123" object, so that when I update "board123" in one list that is automagically reflected in the other. But there are no pointers in Python.

I could hack my way around this and make the 2 lists filled with hash entries. Each board has a unique hash calculated from its current contents. The boards are stored in a third, seperate dictionary where the hash's are the keys.

What do you guys think is the best way to change my "board123" variable in each one of my two lists?

Comment: `list` objects *do not contain variables*, they contain objects. If you want to be able to modify both objects, then fill your lists *with the same object*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct there's no direct concept of "pointers" in python.

However, python does some magic behind the scenes which you can use.

For example

```py
a = [1,2,3,4]
print(a)
# prints [1,2,3,4]

b = a # MAGIC!

print(b)
#prints [1,2,3,4]

a.append(5)
print(a)
#prints [1,2,3,4,5]

print(b)
#prints [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Both a and b are pointing to the same piece of memory.

At any point if you wish for them to "different" you could do something like this:

```py
b = a.copy() # b is no longer related to a!
```

Comment: So I am misunderstanding how objects work in python. Huh. Alright. I thought the two lists would get different copies of the objects. Thanks for the explanation.